# How to delete the shape(circle) on google map when tap on marker?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, maps

I can add many markers and circles on google map with in "didTapAt" event, but I want to delete them as well, for markers I can do this in "didTap marker" event but how can I delete its shape not other shape?

Answer (score 3):

```
let circle = GMSCircle(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7336299, longitude: 30.1616061, radius: 10)
 circle.isTappable = true
 circle.map = mapView

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {
    overlay.map = nil
}
```

Comment: but the problem is i want to hide them the same time, is there any way to do that?

Comment: when you set overlay.map = nil circle will remove from mapView if you want to show again set circle.map = mapView (Can you accept answer)

Comment: the actual problem how can I access to marker in didTap overlay, or overlay in didTap marker? cause when I tab on marker just marker would go away not the overlay, and it's multi select on map

Comment: marker and overlay are different things, you need to know which marker or overlay you want to access in didTap event. If you have multiple markers you can store in array and you can access marker in overlay's didTap method like this;
`var markers = [GMSMarker]()  
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {
        overlay.map = nil
        markers[0].map = nil
    }let circle = GMSCircle(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7336299, longitude: 30.1616061), radius: 10)
        circle.isTappable = true
        circle.map = mapView`

Comment: that is true, tanx so much