# Remove GMSCircle from google map on tap of button

Tags: swift, google-maps

I got multiple lat and Lon on basis of that I have to plot a circle now problem what I'm facing after plotting circle on tap of button if have remove these circles and I got multiple overlays which I don't want to remove I have to only remove circles.
Here's what I have I tried

```
  for  (index,restaurantsPin) in RainData.enumerated() {
                   let latDouble = Double(restaurantsPin.longitude)
                   let longDouble = Double(restaurantsPin.latitude)
                  let circleCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latDouble,longDouble)
                  let circ = GMSCircle(position: circleCenter, radius: 800)


            if buttonpressed == 1 {
             //plotting circle
               circ.fillColor = UIColor(red: 43/255, green: 173, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.9)
               circ.strokeColor = UIColor.red
              circ.strokeWidth = 1
                 circ.map = mapView


            }
            if buttonpressed  == 0{

        circ.map  = nil

            }


                   }
```

Comment: I cannot use mapView.clear because it remove all overlays and markers and shapes.

Comment: circ.map  = nil. not removing circles which I plotted.

Comment: This answer hopefully helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/51596673/11742502

Comment: thanks it helped me out

Comment: Glad to hear! :)